# ASP.Net Core 3.1 Nested Models not posting back

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model, null

My Objects (which are also Models) are not getting posted back to the server.

HomeController.cs Snippet, this is the initial loading, works fine

```
public IActionResult AddCharacter()
{
    CharacterModel character = new CharacterModel();
    character.Servers = ServerController.GetServers();

    return View("AddCharacter",character);
}
```

The post action:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult AddCharacter(CharacterModel character)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         return RedirectToAction("Characters");
     }

     return View(character);
 }
```

This is the form group for server selection, it populates the first time.

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label asp-for="Server">Server</label>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Server, new SelectList(Model.Servers, "Id", "Name", Model.Server), "-- Select Server --", new { @class = "form-control" })
     <span asp-validation-for="Server" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

The submit for the form

```
<div class="form-group">
     input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" formaction="AddCharacter" />
     <input type="submit" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-danger" formaction="CancelAddCharacter" formnovalidate />
</div>
```

This is in the post function inspect, everything is null which is a Model

[image: This is in the post function, everything is null which is a Model]

I don't understand why this is not working, is there something I am missing on the html side to send back the data. Here is the initial Model which is passed down, you can see that things are becoming null on the post.

[image: most things are set]

Comment: You check the actual request and posted data in browser f12 developer tool Network tab. And you can check [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to know more about what model binding is and how it works.

Comment: It looks like it is posting back the values, and not objects, it also isn't posting back the objects that already exist on the model.

All the Models have the [BindProperties] attribute already set.

Comment: `It looks like it is posting back the values, and not objects` in form sub, the posted form fields with values are expected behavior, it would not be objects. And model binding is a process that maps form values to .NET types automatically. If you'd like to make these properties of complex types be bound automatically, you can construct/generate form data on client side manually (using hidden field or js code etc).

Comment: I suggest that you can know how form tag and model binding works first, which would help understand and troubleshoot the model binding related issue.